# How can i make sure RXJava Observable emits only and exactly 1 item

Tags: rx-java

I have an use case which I have to validate that the RXJava Observable emits only 1 item (no more and no less), I know it is an asynchronous world and the Observable should define a timeout period in order to close the stream and by then we can realize the observable emitted 0 or 1 or more items, the problem I have is related to performance and timeouts values because it may impact my customer services. Here is my current code and I want to improve it avoiding blocking statements in the new code:

```
import rx.Observable;
...
Observable<Items> oItems = service.getItems(requestParams);
List resultData = new ArrayList();
oItems .toBlocking().subscribe((arg) -> {
    resultData.add(arg.getId());
}
if (resultData.size() == 1) {
    return Observable.just(resultData.get(0));
}
return Observable.empty();
```

Thank you for your thoughs and ideas.

Comment: Declare the service API as `Single` and you are guaranteed to get 1 item. Otherwise, use `singleOrError` to fail if there is no or more than 1 item.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd, great idea, it worked perfect for my case, but in my rxJava version, I was able to use SingleOrDefault instead of singleOrError.

Comment: Sorry to post on an unrelated question... you deleted your answer too fast. Clarification about the question should be posted as a comment beneath the question, not as an answer. Once you have enough rep, you will be able to leave such comments on other people's questions. It does not require much. In the meantime, please only answer questions which are unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

use `.scan()` so it will be:

```
Observable<Boolean> isOneItemObservable = oItems
    .scan(0, (amount, o) -> amount + 1)
    .map( amount -> amount == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for scan idea, I will try both the scan and the singleOrError approaches and see which one has the best performance time.